# nested json to tsv in databricks pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, pyspark

Want to convert a nested json to tsv in databricks notebook using pysoark.

Below is json structure where columns can be changed.

```
{"tables":[{"name":"Result","columns":[{"name":"JobTime","type":"datetime"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"}]
,"rows":[
["2020-04-19T13:45:12.528Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T14:05:40.098Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T13:46:31.655Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T14:01:16.275Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:03:16.073Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:01:16.672Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:02:13.958Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:04:41.099Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:04:41.16Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:05:14.462Z","Failed"]
]}
]}
```

I am new in databricks Please help

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you have two ways to deal with this problem. Either you do some preprocessing in `python` with `json` library (or equivalent), or you load directly into `pyspark` and play around such as:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# your json
so_json = """
{"tables":[{"name":"Result","columns":[{"name":"JobTime","type":"datetime"},{"name":"Status","type":"string"}]
,"rows":[
["2020-04-19T13:45:12.528Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T14:05:40.098Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T13:46:31.655Z","Failed"]
,["2020-04-19T14:01:16.275Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:03:16.073Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:01:16.672Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:02:13.958Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:04:41.099Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:04:41.16Z","Failed"],
["2020-04-19T14:05:14.462Z","Failed"]
]}
]}
"""

# load in directly using read.json(), you'll see that this becomes 
# a nested ArrayType/StructType wombo combo
json_df = spark.read.json(spark._sc.parallelize([so_json]))
json_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- tables: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- columns: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rows: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


# select nested columns "tables" and "rows" and explode
array_df = json_df.select(f.explode(f.col('tables')['rows'][0]))
```

Exploding takes the `rows` which is `ArrayType` and splits it into actual rows.
Then you can subselect either by dot or slice notation

```
array_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


tabular_df = array_df.select(
  array_df.col[0].alias("JobTime"), 
  array_df.col[1].alias("Status")
)
tabular_df.show()

+--------------------+------+
|             JobTime|Status|
+--------------------+------+
|2020-04-19T13:45:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:05:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T13:46:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:01:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:03:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:01:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:02:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:04:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:04:...|Failed|
|2020-04-19T14:05:...|Failed|
+--------------------+------+
```

Finally, you want to save as CSV with a custom separator (`\t`). Hence:

```
tabular_df.write.csv("path/to/file.tsv", sep="\t")
```

NB: You may need to manually control for types, such as converting `JobTime` to `TimestampType`, but I'll leave that up to you. 
Hope this helps.